# Learning RegEx, is it possible to collect data *after* a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So for instance if I had this string :

```
"color=green&animal=panda"
```

Is it possible that I can with regex, return `green` because it is after `color=` ?

Comment: yes, you could use a regex for this, but those look like url-encoded args..you're probably better off finding a function to decode that into an object. (which might also use a regex, but at least it will be a more generalized solution that will nab all the vars in one shot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JavaScript does **not** support look-behinds (unfortunately), you can only do that by including the preceding sub-string. Group `green`, and refer to the group.

```
var string = "color=green&animal=panda";
var pattern = /color=(green)/;
var match = pattern.exec(string);
var wantedstring = match[1];
```

Look-aheads do exist though, so the following can be used to match "green", but not "greener":

```
var pattern = /color=(green)(?=&|$)/;
```

Comment: @Trip No, not really. Matching a little context and returning the contents of a group is standard procedure with regex. You're probably over-thinking your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly:

```
"color=green&animal=panda".replace(/.*color=(.+?)&.*/, '$1') === 'green';
```

That pattern extracts any characters following a `color=` and followed by an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. We call this matching groups. <strike>Here's what your regex could be:</strike>

```
/color=(.+?)(?:&|#|$)/
```

It will match everything between the parenthesis. In this case, anything (`.+`) after the string `color=` up to the first `&` char

The regex could be `/color=([^&]+)/`, see Tomalak comments for explanations :)

Comment: I would recommend `/color=([^&]+)/`, though. Yours fails if the `color` is the last parameter in the string. Not to forget that you need to apply `decodeURIComponent` to the match to get the actual value.

Comment: I've edit the regex, `(?:&|$)` instead of `&` now match a `&` char or the end of the string

Comment: Still fails if a `#` hash is present. Just take the character class, it will be sorter.

Comment: exact. Yeah it might be shorter but negative classes like this `[^whatever]` don't perform very well, so when I can avoid them I prefer doing so :)

Comment: Where did you hear *that*? That's nonsense, especially as such a generalized statement. http://jsperf.com/character-class-performance

Comment: Well, in most cases, it is faster to do "something equals to someOtherting" than doing "something NOT equals to someOtherting", "positive" verification is faster than negative one. And also, I always prefer saying "only THIS is allowed" than "allow EVERYTHING but that", it's safer :)

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions about how regex engines work, and in this case your assumption is just wrong.

Comment: Okay, so do you have some links/docs/whatever where I can learn how regex engines works ? I'm curious to learn about about that :)

Comment: Try ["Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1331217936&sr=8-1)